# SwiftUI app crashes when trying to expand/collapse sections on a sheet

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

The idea is that when user clicks on the headers,they expand revealing the controls.

It crashes when I expand one of the sections, then click in the TextField and then click on a different section to make the current one collapse and the other one to expand.

Things to note:

1. This is only a problem with 'sheet'. If I present the DetailView via NavigationLink, it works perfectly
2. It only happens if I click on the TextField. If I just expand/collapse sections - everything works
3. Xcode 11.6, targeting and running on iOS 13.6

What is wrong with my code? Or is it a bug in SwiftUI?

I distilled the offending code into the smallest working example

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var name: String = "Default name"
    
    @State var location: String = "Default location"
    
    @State var expanded : Int = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button (action: {self.expanded = 0}) {
                HStack {
                    Text(self.name).font(.caption)
                    Spacer()
                    Image (systemName: "chevron.right")
                }
            }
            if self.expanded == 0 {
                TextField ("Enter name", text: self.$name)
            }
            
            Button (action: {self.expanded = 1}) {
                HStack {
                    Text(self.location).font(.caption)
                    Spacer()
                    Image (systemName: "chevron.right")
                }
            }
            if self.expanded == 1 {
                TextField ("Enter location", text: self.$location)
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
 }


 struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showDetail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Button ("Detail") {
                self.showDetail = true
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetail, content: {DetailView()})
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No crash with Xcode12b3 / iOS 14.

Comment: @Asperi thanks, good to know. Does it crash for you on xcode 11/iOS 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone lands here from google, it ended up being the same problem as here [SwiftUI iOS app crashes when state change causes keyboard to resign as first responder while in a sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952203/swiftui-ios-app-crashes-when-state-change-causes-keyboard-to-resign-as-first-res)

In my case however the stack was unhelpfully empty and only after countless attempts did I get one that had `ViewRendererHost.render` on top apart from generic 'main' event loop. Sure enough googling it immediately produced the above link

Reported this to Apple. It's clearly a bug in SwiftUI